# How to connect 3 different programs in one main file using pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have 3 programs here, and I have a problem in running those 3 programs because I want it to be all imported to the main file and connected to each other after clicking the buttons on each window. My problem here is that after I have reached the 2nd window, when I click the button there then it doesn't proceed to the last window but instead the window crashes. What would I change in my program so that it will not crash?

s1.py (main program)

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from s4 import *
from s3 import *

class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def ok (self):
        self.window=QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui=Ui_MainWindow2()
        self.ui.setup(self.window)
        self.window.show()
        MainWindow.hide()
    def proceed (self):
        self.window1=QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui1=Ui_MainWindow3()
        self.ui1.setup1(self.window1)
        self.window1.show()
        MainWindow2.hide()

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 220, 93, 28))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.ok)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ok"))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

s4.py (2nd program)

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from s3 import *

class Ui_MainWindow2(object):

    def proceed (self):
        self.window1=QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui1=Ui_MainWindow3()
        self.ui1.setup1(self.window1)
        self.window1.show()
        MainWindow2.hide()


    def setup(self, MainWindow2):
        MainWindow2.setObjectName("MainWindow2")
        MainWindow2.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow2)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 270, 93, 28))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.proceed)
        MainWindow2.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow2)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow2.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow2)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow2.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow2)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow2)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow2):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow2.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow2", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow2", "PROCEED"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow2 = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow2()
    ui.setup(MainWindow2)
    MainWindow2.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

s3.py(3rd program)

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow3(object):
    def setup1(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 190, 451, 181))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "THIS IS MY LAST WINDOW"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow3()
    ui.setup1(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: well, you could start to copy and paste the codes, and then show us the output of the your interpreter. With that, it is easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from s4 import Ui_MainWindow2


class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def ok (self):
        self.window=QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui=Ui_MainWindow2()
        self.ui.setup(self.window)
        self.window.show()
        MainWindow.hide()


    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 220, 93, 28))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.ok)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ok"))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and import Ui_MainWindow3 from s3.py  into s4 file and call proceed function as well as:

```
from s3 import Ui_MainWindow3
```

Comment: Still I have a problem when it proceeds to the last window because it doesn't display anything in the last window. Should I import the s3.py only in the s4 file? or also in the s1 file? Lastly for the proceed function is there something wrong on how I called it in the s4 file? or I must call it on the s1 file?